# How to replace EasyPeasy partition with Lubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows, lubuntu

I have acer netbook with dual boot, window 7 and Easy Peasy . I want to replace EasyPeasy partition with Lubuntu so that I have dual boot of window 7 and lubuntu.  Please let me know how can do it.

Comment: That question should answer your problems. You would just install Lubuntu over the EasyPeasy partition.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Boot into the installation disk and install as usual.
2. When you get to the prompt asking you how to install, select Something Else
3. Remove all of the Easy Peasy partitions from the partition editor.
4. Give Lubuntu a main partition and a swap partition.
5. Continue.
6. Profit!

Comment: Alternatively: choose the same partition(s) of EasyPeasy, and make sure you check the option that formats those partitions. The Ubuntu installer will recognize the swap partition automatically.